# Given that $T=\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}$, where $x, y, T \in\Bbb R$, show that $\frac{1+T^2}{2T}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given that $T=\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}$, where $x, y, T \in\Bbb R$, show that $$\frac{1+T^2}{2T}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

I have got rid of $i$ in the denominator, leaving $$\frac{x^2-y^2-2ixy}{x^2+y^2}$$
but now I am stuck. What are the next steps please?

Comment: The statement is true for all $T\in \mathbb{C}$. The restriction $T\in \mathbb{R}$ is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to note that our expression is equal to 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{T}+T\right).$$
Substituting, we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}+\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}    \right).$$
Bring to the common denominator $x^2+y^2$. The top is then $(x+iy)^2+(x-iy)^2=2x^2-2y^2$, and we are finished.

Answer (score 2):

You made an error somewhere.

Writing $T = \frac{a}{b}$, the expression you are trying to simplify is

$$\frac{1+\frac{a^2}{b^2}}{2\frac{a}{b}}$$
which after clearing out the denominators is
$$\frac{b^2+a^2}{2ab}.$$

Plugging in $a$ and $b$ and using the fact that they are complex conjugates gives
$$\frac{x^2 +2ixy - y^2 + x^2 -2ixy - y^2}{2(x^2+y^2)}$$
which simplifies to the expression you want.

Comment: You accidentally wrote $y^2$ instead of $-y^2$ in your final expression.

Comment: @Alraxite Thanks, fixed